# How to set basic vanilla javascript if statement to set cookies

Tags: javascript

Need to set a cookie so an age-gate only shows once on the site.

I was trying to use a plugin from the CMS but it's too new of a version for the current site. So I am at a lost at the moment, don't even know where to begin really.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var age__gate = document.querySelector(".age__content");
        var age__gate__no = document.querySelector(".age__no");
        var age__check = document.querySelector(".age__check");

        var age__button__no = document.getElementById("age__No");
        var age__button__yes = document.getElementById("age__Yes");


        age__button__no.addEventListener("click", function() {
            age__gate.classList.add("is-active");
            age__gate__no.classList.add("is-active");
        });

        age__button__yes.addEventListener("click", function() {
            age__check.classList.add("is-active");

            document.cookie = 'age_confirmed=checked';
        });
 </script>
```

So this is the script that I have so far. I just need a way to attach the age_confirmed=checked to the popup itself so it doesn't show. The cookie is stored fine in the backend but now that the CMS code doesn't work I am at a lost. Any help to get this working would be great :)

EDIT

The whole CMS is not broken, just the plugin to store cookies is.

I feel like something along the lines should work;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var age__gate = document.querySelector(".age__content");
        var age__gate__no = document.querySelector(".age__no");
        var age__check = document.querySelector(".age__check");

        var age__button__no = document.getElementById("age__No");
        var age__button__yes = document.getElementById("age__Yes");


        age__button__no.addEventListener("click", function() {
            age__gate.classList.add("is-active");
            age__gate__no.classList.add("is-active");
        });

        age__button__yes.addEventListener("click", function() {
            age__check.classList.add("is-active");

            document.cookie = 'age_confirmed=checked';

           if (age_confirmed == checked) {

            age__check.classList.remove("is-active");

           }
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage perhaps?

Comment: It's unclear what's at stake if your *whatever CMS* is broken...

Comment: Hi just added in what I think should be ok but I don't know. Thanks for getting back to me though :)

Answer (score 1):

Before you fix your CMS/Backend/Whatever you can play with [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage) - which (at least in Europe) conforms to the same regulations as storing a Cookie

Having this HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="age">Let me in, I am 18+</label>
```

here's the JavaScript

```js
// Put this chunk on every page (Fails if unset or if value is "minor")

if (localStorage.age !== 'adult') alert("You're not of legal age to see this content");



// Put this chunk where needed

const EL_age = document.querySelector("#age");
EL_age.addEventListener('change', () =>  localStorage.age = EL_age.checked ? 'adult' : 'minor');
EL_age.checked = localStorage.getItem('age') === 'adult'; // If found - update checkbox state
```